# Convert formula to a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below formula: from sheet "L010" different column SUM the value and return to sheet "Productie Detaliata: in a specific cell the value. In the file I have a loot of this formulas and the workbook work very slow because every time when I open run all this formula. Its possible to have this in a script?

=Iferror(FILTER('L010'!$J$3;'L010'!$I$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$L$3;'L010'!$K$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$N$3;'L010'!$M$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$P$3;'L010'!$O$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$R$3;'L010'!$Q$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$W$3;'L010'!$V$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$Y$3;'L010'!$X$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AA$3;'L010'!$Z$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AC$3;'L010'!$AB$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AE$3;'L010'!$AD$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AJ$3;#REF!=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AL$3;'L010'!$AK$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AN$3;'L010'!$AM$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AP$3;'L010'!$AO$3=C2);0)+iferror(FILTER('L010'!$AR$3;'L010'!$AQ$3=C2);0)

Comment: You do know there is an error in your formula `#REF`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.